# Pass values from to 2 different activities to the one that is not startActivity

Tags: android, android-activity

The activity that i want to pass values is main activity-menu of app. From this activity i do startActivity the all activity with buttons. I want to retrieve values from two different activities at the same time as I mentioned to the title and when I startActivity each actity i want to send values.Any help?

Comment: What kind of values are you trying to pass? Are they simple primitive values like int and string?

Comment: its strings values

Answer (score 1):

**Use Static fields or methods**

Have Static String fields (or methods to compute and then return strings) in all classes that you want to get values from, then have your activity-menu get them and pass them into the your `startActivity` intent.

Example:

```
class activity-menu extends Activity{

    public void StartActivityC(){
        // Get value from Activity_A
        string value_A = Activity_A.myString;
        // Get value from Activity_B
        string value_B = Activity_B.myString;
        // Store both values in an Intent:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity_C.class);
         // store the string from Activity A under "value_A"
        intent.putExtra("value_A", value_A);
         // store the string from Activity B under "value_B"
        intent.putExtra("value_B", value_B);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}

public class Activity_A extends Activity{
    public static String myString;
    public Activity_A(){
        myString = "this is from activity A";
    }
}

public class Activity_B extends Activity{
    public static String myString;
    public Activity_B(){
        myString = "this is from activity B";
    }
}

public class Activity_C extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the strings:
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String value_A = intent.getStringExtra("value_A");
        string value_B = intent.getStringExtra("value_B");

        // DONE!
    }   
}
```

Comment: can you give an example?

Comment: Sure, can you please copy-paste what code you're using in activity-menu so far for me to base it of?